# Change split image in ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionmode, actionmode

I have to change the split image of a done [tick mark] button in ActionMode, i have tried style splitBackground and other ways but not able to change it.

The attached image with red arrow.[image]

Please help me to find the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to change the split image

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!– All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. –>
        <!– ABS attributes (required for backwards compatibility: http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) –>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_cab_done_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode</item>

        <!– Android SDK attributes –>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_cab_done_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode</item>
</style>
```

Source: http://www.codercowboy.com/2013/07/05/styling-the-contextual-action-bar-actionmode-divider-or-splitter-for-android/